# Why does the compiler use the copy constructor on my lambda instead of the move constructor?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, move-semantics

I'm trying to use the generalized capture syntax to move a `unique_ptr` to a lambda before wrapping it in a `std::function`. The code is straightforward enough:

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unique_ptr<int> x;
    function<void()> y = [x(move(x))]() {};
}
```

This selects the `template<typename T> function(T t)` constructor, but it fails because it tries to copy the lambda. Why is it invoking the copy constructor instead of the move constructor, and what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: `std::function` doesn't support move-only types

Answer (score 3):

`std::function` can only be used with CopyConstructible types, see [LWG 1287](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#1287) which clarified this.

If your type isn't copyable you can't put it in a `std::function`.